# Can Hydraulic System work on a Moon Robot?

Tags: classical-mechanics, temperature, moon

Since the Moon has no atmosphere and the temperatures reach maximum 123 C and min minus 153 C, how feasible is it to use hydraulic actuators to move the Robot legs?

Since my assistant Professor insists on going forward with the idea of building a smaller scaled model using the hydraulic system, i was a bit skeptic and wanted to know if it is actually doable. 
For the record the Robot will run with batteries with max capacity of around 25000 mAh. I thought it was important to mention that because of the possibility to keep the hydraulics System within operation temperatures. 
The robot should also be able to handle around 1000 N of load.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, hydraulics will work - as long as you use a fluid that has a working range relevant to the ambient conditions.

Skydrol is used on aircraft as it has the properties deemed necessary... not the nicest stuff if you get it on skin etc...

Answer (score 0):

yes hydraulics could be made to work, the lack of air pressure is no big problem since hydraulic pressures will be fairly high, a few missing psi externally wouldn't really matter. The biggest problem would be having a hydraulic fluid with a multi-viscosity to handle the extreme temperature variations. Also any hoses or seals would have to remain flexible and pressure proof at those extremes.